# how to create iphone like tabs layout in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How can i create iphone like tabs layout in a blackberry java application for all types of blackberry devices(scrollpad/touch screen). Are there any alternatives to achieve that effect? could you please suggest me in that way?

thanks,
venu

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
I had to create tabs in blackberry so for this this i tried a custom way which fulfilled my requirement.May be u can use and customize this idea.

1) create a method **addTab()** in a class and place say 5 bitmap fields(components) in that.
2) place these components in an horizontal field manager
3) **addTab()** method must return this manager.
4) create a method **result()** in that class that must be called whenever the components(Bitmap fields) are clicked.

Now in your main class wherever you want to display the tabs:
1) create object for that class and do

```
add(obj.addTab());
```

or u can do :

```
setStatus(obj.addTab());
```

depending upon your requirement